# Is the following triangulation valid?

Tags: geometry, triangulation

Consider the following polygon with 10 vertices such that $H,G,F,I$ are colinear:

[image]

Note that it is known that any triangulation of a polygon with $n$ vertices gives has $n-2$ triangles. In the figure above, we have 10 vertices but only 6 triangles. Is this a valid triangulation? Or perhaps I is it possible that I cannot take $\triangle JHI$ as a single triangle since that would mean intersecting with the original polygon too many times (it also intersects with $G$ and $F$)?

Comment: The red triangle is not really a triangle in the sense of a triangulation since it has 5 vertices.

Comment: Indeed I suspected that from the beginning. So just to clarify, in any triangulation, all the triangles can only have 3 vertices?

Comment: @TheValars Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any triangle in a triangulation must have exactly 3 vertices. (I'm answering this under community wiki so the question can be marked as answered.)